# How to validate all entered properties in just one line?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I want to validate my all properties in Input but it doesn't work here

```
    <input id="cardCode" ngModel #cardCode="ngModel" name="cardCode" type="tel" required maxlength="3" required minlength="3" class="form-control cc-cvc" required autocomplete="off">

   <div  style="background-color:orange;font-weight: bold;"                               
    *ngIf="cardCode.touched && cardCode.errors?.required &&
  cardCode.errors?.required" >
   This is not valid CVC </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div  style="background-color:orange;font-weight: bold;"                              
 *ngIf="cardCode.touched && !cardCode.valid" >
 This is not valid CVC </div>
```

angular adds an invalid class based on the validators.

Comment: Thanks for answer!What about adding patterns also in this ngIf?That was my question actually also I forgot to add

Comment: Yes you can give a pattern like this `<input name="something" ngModel pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">`

Comment: when I try to correct after error occurs,I want to disappear that error in your solution still error is there until statement getting correct.I just want to see error only when its untouched and invalid

Comment: and also one doesn't add patterns to the ngIf structural directive, you should only give an expression which returns boolean

Comment: I meant without patterns .Just based on your answer

Comment: I edited my answer try using !valid like I did and if it doesn't work put a StackBlitz of your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199435/discussion-between-ramesh-and-timucin-cicek).

Comment: Please be sure to update both the question and the answer with whatever you come up with in chat. It's annoying to come to these kinds of Q&A pairs from search and not know what happened... :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah sure I'll do that